# How to re-select selected option back to same state in HTML on form reset or on cancel button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Scenario, where I need to show user back the system selected option when user wants to cancel or reset the form after made some selection change on select element. (catch here is reset form select element, back to default selected option value in the view on cancel or reset form)

```
 <button>Reset</button>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>  
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="jbselect">
      <option>a</option>
      <option >b</option>
      <option selected>c</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, I found to the question I have.

```
document.querySelector('.jsPaymentStatusOptions option[selected]').index // find the selected option and its index value, in my case it returns 3
document.querySelector('.jsPaymentStatusOptions').selectedIndex = 3 // then set that index value to the select selectedIndex property it works.
```

self discovered from another thread, where answer suggested to use like option:checked (but which gives user changed current selected option in return):

```
document.querySelector('.jsPaymentStatusOptions option:checked')
```

What I want to achieve is this: https://codepen.io/tortoisefeel/pen/MWXrQQe (jQuery Way)

here is pure Javascript way: https://codepen.io/tortoisefeel/pen/MWXrQxJ

resetting select back to last selection option once user don't take action if the selection is in the view of page.
Hope this helps out to someone in search. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to keep a history of the choices and allow rolling back the value for each click of the reset button...

```js
let history = []
$(function() {
  $('.jbselect').change(function() {
    history.push($(this).val());
  })
  // start it off
  history.push($('.jbselect').val());
})

$("button").click(function() {
  if (history.length == 1) return
  // remove latest value
  history.splice(-1, 1)
  $('.jbselect').val(history.at(-1))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Reset</button>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select class="jbselect">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option selected>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sounds too much for small cases, one or two liner would be great!